# exclude get parameter from mo rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

http://site.ru/?pages=(.*?)

How to exclude it from mod_rewrite

I tried something like this

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(images|\?pages=.*?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

#<IfModule mod_security.c>
#SecFilterEngine Off
#SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule security_module>
#SecFilterEngine Off
#SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>
#<IfModule security2_module>
#SecFilterEngine Off
#SecFilterScanPOST Off
#</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   !/images [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !(^|&)pages= [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

i.e. use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` to match a query parameter.

Comment: Provide more details since `!(^|&)pages=` will exclude even empty `?page=` URLs